# how to hide a string on re-render in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button inside a functional component which on click displays a string. I want to know how to hide that string when the component is re-rendered or there is any  state change.

```
<button onClick = {() => props.getstring (props.state)} >Click </button>
{props.state.string}
```

So, when I click this button, the string is displayed but it stays on the screen when there is a state change. I want to hide it when any state value changes.

Answer (score 0):

you can use react life-cycle methods to do that. As you need to get component update event you can use `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate`

```
getSnapshotBeforeUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: will this work with functional components also ? because I dont have state in the component where I write this button

Comment: No, it cannot be used in functional components, you have to convert code to React.Component class

Comment: If you cannot have another class then use `useEffect(didUpdate);`. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect

Answer (score 0):

You need a [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) Hook **(Added in React16.8)** for this,

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const [isHidden, setIsHidden] = useState(false);

useEffect(
  () => {
    setIsHidden(true);
  },
  [props.state],
);

//Now the setIsHidden will only be called when props.state changes.
```

and then you can hide string,

```
{!isHidden && props.state.string}
```

Comment: Okay so IsHidden property will be set to false when button is clicked ?

Comment: This is as per your requirement, if you need to make your data visible on click of button then you need to call `setIsHidden(false)`, like this `<button onClick = {() => setIsHidden(false)} >Click </button>`